# dismissViewControllerAnimated didn't work if monitor is connected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

I have main view controller and I use these following code to show next view and dismiss that view.They are working perfectly if there is no external monitor attached. If it is attached, I can't dismiss the view controller already although I can present that view controller. How shall I do?

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];


[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

This is for external monitor view.

```
externalDisplayHandler = [[ExternalDisplayHandler alloc] init];
externalDisplayHandler.delegate = self;

if(externalDisplayHandler.monitorExists)
{

    //other code

    NSLog(@"externalDisplayHandler.monitorExists");
     [externalDisplayHandler.contentView addSubview:viewOnMonitor];

    NSLog(@"TV is attached");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now remember that there are other ways too. I change to this combination.

```
[self presentViewController:lMVC animated:YES completion:nil];

[self.presentingViewController  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```